# Flex: How to tell when a component (and it's children) are done updating

Tags: apache-flex

I'm resizing a chart and want to take a picture of it when all the children of that chart are done updating.

For example I'm drawing some stuff on the chart after the size changes.  I've tried chaining a bunch of callLater() but I'm still running into problems on slow computers.

Raising an event when the last children has executed doesn't seem to work as it might take a while to draw (hence the callLaters).

Is there a best practice to find out when something is done updating?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the chart you're using follows Flex Component LifeCycle conventions; try listening to the updateComplete event.